# Can't initialize a vector of unique_ptr in class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, initialization

Currently, I have two classes, `Ai` and `Action`.

My class `Ai` gets a member `Action` called `_root`.

```
class Ai
{
  public:
    Ai();
    ~Ai();
  private:
    Action _root;
};
```

The problem happens when I want to initialize my class `Action` with my constructor `Ai`.

```
Ai::Ai() : _root(Action(0, AI, 0, 0)) 
{
}
```

My class`Action` with my constructor:

```
class Action
{
public:
  Action(int, Availability, int, int);
  ~Action();
  private:
    int _y;
    int _x;
    int _depth;
    Availability _type;
    vector<unique_ptr<Action>> _child;
};

Action::Action(int depth, Availability type, int y, int x)
{
  this->_y = y;
  this->_x = x;
  this->_depth = depth;
  this->_type = type;
}
```

The problem happens precisely with `vector<unique_ptr<Action>> _child;`.

When I create an object `Ai`, my constructor creates an object `Action` with default values, but it can not initialize the vector of `unique_ptr`.

My debugger got me this error :

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of
  'std::__1::unique_ptr<Action, std::__1::default_delete<Action> >'
        ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
```

Any idea?

Comment: You copy-construct the `_root` member, but the class `Action` can't be copied because of the vector. It needs to be [*moved*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move). Please read more about move-semantics and [move constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you've declared the `Ai` constructor, you're creating a *temporary* `Action` object, then copying that to `_root`.

The solution is simple:

```
Ai::Ai() : _root(0, AI, 0, 0)
```

Pass the constructor arguments to `_root` directly.

Unrelated, you don't need to use `this->` to access the member variables in `Action::Action`.

Answer (score 0):

The class `Action` doesn't a user-defined move constructor. It does have a user-defined destructor that prevents automatic generation of a move constuctor. `Action` has at least one member (`_child`) that cannot be copied. Hence, `Action` has no copy constructor either.

In C++11 `_root(Action(0, AI, 0, 0))` can only be performed if `Action` has accessible either copy or move constructor. It has neither. To solve the problem, you either construct `_root` directly (see **1201ProgramAlarm**'s answer), or ask a compiler to generate a move constructor for you by adding

```
Action(Action&&) = default;
```

[See this example](https://godbolt.org/z/X96QYZ) for C++11

---

In C++17 rules have changed, and `_root(Action(0, AI, 0, 0))` is equivalent to `_root(0, AI, 0, 0)` due to [mandatory copy/move elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). The code should compile without copy and move constructors available (unless there are other reasons for compilation to fail).

[See this example](https://godbolt.org/z/8ySWWy) for C++17